# Split text using regex ignore new line

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

If I have a div tag like

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="textbox">
  Hi<br/>
  I am a multline<br/>
  value
</div>
```

I want to split it using regex

```
var sTextboxSplit = sTextbox.split(/[\s,]+/); 
var sTextboxLast = sTextboxSplit[sTextboxSplit.length - 1];
```

but when It goes to new line then in `sTextboxSplit[sTextboxSplit.length - 1]` it added newline also so instead of `sTextboxSplit[2]` it shows `sTextboxSplit[3]`..How to ignore new line???

Comment: you want to get whole line or separate words?

Comment: @m.cekiera whole line after ignoring newline

Comment: unfortunettly this is how split works, use match as a delimeter for split, so if match is on beginning or end of string, it will return also empty string. Consider using matching by regex, not splitting